# Implementing a multi-threaded file downloader in C# with error handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, download, network-programming

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded file downloader in C#. The downloader should be able to download multiple files at once, and each file should be downloaded using a separate thread to increase performance. I have tried using the ThreadPool class, but I am not sure how to manage the threads and ensure that they do not interfere with each other.

Can someone provide me with sample code for implementing a multi-threaded file downloader in C#? Also, how can I handle errors and interruptions during the download process, such as network errors or user cancellation? Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class FileDownloader
{
    private string[] _urls;
    private string _outputFolder;
    private int _maxThreads;

    public FileDownloader(string[] urls, string outputFolder, int maxThreads)
    {
        _urls = urls;
        _outputFolder = outputFolder;
        _maxThreads = maxThreads;
    }

    public void StartDownload()
    {
        // TODO: Implement multi-threaded file downloading
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WhenAll to do it, an example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        List<string> urls = new List<string> {
            "https://example.com/file1.txt",
            "https://example.com/file2.txt",
            "https://example.com/file3.txt"
        };
    List<Task> downloadTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        downloadTasks.Add(DownloadFile(url));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);

    Console.WriteLine("All files downloaded successfully.");
}

public static async Task DownloadFile(string url)
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // do something with the content of the downloaded file
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {url}");
}
```

}

Comment: It’s not a good idea to create a new HttpClient instance for every request. This can lead to port exhaustion and slow requests. Use a single instance for every request.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that uses Microsoft's Reactive Framework:

```
public async Task DownloadFilesAsync(string[] urls, string outputFolder, int maxThreads) =>
    await
    (
        from url in urls.ToObservable()
        from x in Observable.Using(
            () => new WebClient(),
            wc => Observable.FromAsync(() => wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, Path.Combine(outputFolder, Path.GetFileName(url)))))
        select x
    ).ToArray();
```